# Reset metadata for a specific stream only

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

In my usecase I'd like to recode audio streams into a different format with ffmpeg. The source files (MKV) contain a video stream, two audio streams and three subtitle streams as well as chapters. Audio and subtitle streams contain metadata like language or a stream title. I use this command in Windows batch:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" ^
-map 0:v -c:v copy ^
-map 0:s -c:s copy ^
-map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 eac3 -b:a:0 256k ^
-map 0:a:1 -c:a:1 eac3 -b:a:1 256k ^
-map_chapters 0 ^
"output.mkv"
```

Conversion itself works. Unfortunately, after conversion some of the audio metadata appear wrong. E.g. audio stream size shows the size prior conversion. That's why I want to reset the audio metadata without touching metadata of subtitles. To do this, I modified my command:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" ^
-map_metadata 0 ^
-map 0:v -c:v copy ^
-map 0:s -c:s copy ^
-map_metadata:s:a -1 ^
-map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 eac3 -b:a:0 256k -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng ^
-map 0:a:1 -c:a:1 eac3 -b:a:1 256k -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng ^
-map_chapters 0 ^
"output.mkv"
```

With `-map_metadata:s:a -1` I am trying to reset the metadata of the audio streams only. But the problem starts here: it clears also metadata of subtitle streams. I could not figure out until now how to reset audio stream metadata only. Another attempt using

```
-map_metadata:s:a -1 ^
-map_metadata:s:s 0 ^
```

did not help. Metadata (language, stream title) is still deleted for subs. The only metadata which is kept are "default" and "forced" tags.

Of course, I could use `-map 0:s:0 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng` for example. But this is a workaround in my eyes and time consuming to configure for each stream.

Despite using Google for hours and running dozens of tests I could not figure out how to clear only audio metadata and retain everything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need `-map_metadata:s:a -1`; adding any `-map_metadata:s` option disables all default stream metadata copying.  So now you have to manually map every stream... :-( You need to be more specific, so if there is 1 subtitle stream, then it's `-map_metadata:s:s 0:s:s`, but with 3 subtitles it's `-map_metadata:s:s:0 0:s:s:0 -map_metadata:s:s:1 0:s:s:1 -map_metadata:s:s:2 0:s:s:2` and if you also want the video stream metadata then `-map_metadata:s:v:0 0:s:v:0`.